# 16.04 Command line UI reset?

Tags: command-line

I’m a noob trying to set up Ubuntu 16.04 for a Vision-impared user. Under System>Settings, I managed to make the UI so enormous that I can’t change it back to a more reasonable setting. I want to use the console to reset scaling and font sizes to their small values again. How do I do that, please?

Answer (score 2):

OP again. This worked for me just now:
On the command line: dconf reset -f /
Then reboot.
I was then able to get back into System Settings > Displays to reset my scale to a more reasonable value.

Thank you for your patience.